# How to expand image as text overlay expands?

Tags: html, css, image, picturefill

We have the following code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/userrj/pen/YRdbjm). The problem we have is that we are using the `<picture>` attribute to render images based on `viewport`, but are not able to have the image take up the same amount of space as the text that is overlaid on image.

codepin details:

1. currently the text has `background-color: #eee` so you can see the area the text takes up.
2. Image and text have `position: absolute`, but open to change it.
3. based on the `viewport`, we always want the image from the `<source>` tag to only take up what the text takes up.

**Goal:**

1. make image take up the same height and width as the text overlaid on top
2. use `<picture>` and `<source>`
3. not use `style: background-image('path/to/image')` on `<div class="item__img">`
4. open to cropping image to make it fit, but would prefer it be done without the cropping.

**Current issue:**
[image: curernt issue]

**Desired output**
[image: desired output]

How can we have the `image` expand as the text on top of it expands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image is always bigger than the textbox, here's a solution

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}
  
.item__img img {
  width: 100% !important;
}
 
.item__text {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(238,238,238, 0.5);
  padding: 32px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item__img">
    <picture>
      <source media="(min-width: 1300px)" srcset="https://placeimg.com/1000/480/nature">
      <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" srcset="https://placeimg.com/960/480/nature">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
    </picture>
  </div>
  <div class="item__text">
    <div>
      <h3>Some title</h3>
      <p>Efficiently communicate sticky quality vectors after compelling growth strategies. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You coud use `object-fit` property on your img:

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 33%;
}

img{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}

.item__text {
  background-color: #eee;
  opacity: 0.5;
  padding:32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
 <div class="item__img">
  <picture>
   <source media="(min-width: 1300px)" srcset="https://placeimg.com/1000/480/nature">
   <source media="(min-width: 1024px)" srcset="https://placeimg.com/960/480/nature">
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" alt="Flowers">
  </picture>
 </div>
 <div class="item__text">
  <h3>Some title</h3>
  <p>Efficiently communicate sticky quality vectors after compelling growth strategies. </p>
 </div>
</div>
```